# Making a Room DAO class implement another interface

Tags: android, android-room

I have a domain layer and data layer. Is it possible to do this?

**Domain**: `User.java`        `UserDao.java`

**Data**: `UserRoomEntity.java`       `UserRoomDao.java`

I want all my data sources to implement the `UserDao`. When i make `UserRoomDao` implements `UserDao` interface i get errors that i should annotate the `UserDao.java` function with `@insert` and the rest of Room annotations. Is it possible to do this with Room?

```
@Dao
public abstract class UserRoomDao implments UserDao{

    @Insert
    public abstract void insert(User...users);

    @Update
    public abstract void update(User...users);

    @Delete
    public abstract void delete(User...users);
```

```
public interface UserDao {


    public void insert(UserModel... userModels);

    public void delete(UserModel... userModels);

    public void update(UserModel... userModels);

}
```

i get this error in the `UserDao`.

> error: An abstract DAO method must be annotated with one and only one
>   of the following annotations: Insert, Delete, Query, Update, RawQuery

Comment: Could you please provide some code?

Comment: please give some code of what you want to achieve, even if it doesn't work, just show what you want to achieve

Comment: i have added the code.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to make `UserRoomDao` class `abstract` and the mark the methods in `UserDao` `abstract` so Room will provide the implementations for them.

Comment: I did the that. The UserDao is an interface and the UserRoomDoa is an abstract class. But i get this error when i implement the UserDao in UserRoomDao. error: An abstract DAO method must be annotated with one and only one of the following annotations: Insert,Delete,Query,Update,RawQuery

Answer (score 0):

I extend the UserDao with UserRoomDao interface and override the methods. It works for me.

```
 public interface UserDao {

    Flowable<User> getUser();

    Completable insertUser(User user);

    void deleteAllUsers(); 
}

@Dao
public interface UserRoomDao extends UserDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM Users LIMIT 1")
    Flowable<User> getUser();

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    Completable insertUser(User user);

    @Query("DELETE FROM Users")
    void deleteAllUsers();
}
```

Make sure to return UserRoomDao from UsersDatabase

```
@Database(entities = {User.class}, version = 1)
public abstract class UsersDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

    public abstract UserRoomDao userRoomDao();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing @Dao anotation  in your `UserDao` class. Also you missed `abstract` keyword. so full example like :

```
@Dao
public abstract class UserRoomDao extend UserDao{

    @Insert
    public abstract void insert(User...users);

    @Update
    public abstract void update(User...users);

    @Delete
    public abstract void delete(User...users);
}
```

and change interface to class. (**You can keep both UserDao and UserRoomDao as interface**)

```
public abstract class UserDao {

   @Insert
    public void insert(UserModel... userModels);
    @Update
    public void delete(UserModel... userModels);
   @Delete
    public void update(UserModel... userModels);

}
```

**Suggestion:**
Make generic `dao` class so other dao can use it. Like:

```
@Dao 
public abstract interface MyGenericDao<T>{
        @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
        public abstract long insertOrUpdate(T row);

        @Update
        public abstract int update(T... objects);

        @Delete
        public abstract int delete(T... objects);
    }
```

Now you can use this generic dao in your others dao so for inserting or updating (Generic work) will be covered by generic dao not need to implement any same method again.